# Boy girl paradox and information

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was watching a [TED video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpwSGsb-rTs) about the boy/girl paradox and several questions come up and there are several things I dont understand.

Why is there a paradox? In the TED video they say its 1/3 invariabily, But the ODDs for a frog croaking wouldnt be doubled on the Male/Male subgroup? Meaning the correct answer would be 1/2?

Isnt the same with the original boy/girl paradox?

- John Smith have two children, he introduces one of them as a boy. Wich are the odds the other is also a boy?

If he is introducing at random isnt introducing a boy the double the odds in the boy/boy subgroup? [BB; BG; GB; GG] arent the odds: [50;25;25;0]?

Isnt it showing exactly this? When you take the probabilities of the event happening into account, the odds are always 1/2.

Another example: You are playing poker, you have a very good hand with 80% chance of winning. If someone increases the bet, folds or pay, it makes you wonder whether your chances really are higher or lower than 80%.

Now when adding irrelevant information, as in the **day of the week** boy/girl paradox. I quite dont understand why it changes the probabilities addin irrelevant information, isnt it illogical?

- You pick at random all families with 2 children, with at leat one boy, born on tuesday. The chances of the family consisting of a boy and a girl is 52%.

The same can be said about every other day of the week, it cant? for Monday 52%, Wednesday 52%, Thursday 52%... and so on. If the odds of every day are 52% how can it be 1/2 or even 1/3 if you disconsider the days of the week??

The way I see it is if you have multiple answers for the same problem one of them is wrong.

Cant you just make up information and achieve the same result?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I'm not sure what you're asking? For example "make up information". Also, you're right that it isn't actually a logical paradox -- the point is that it _seems_ paradoxical, because (many) people would say that a wrong answer is intuitively correct. You are also correct that what is exactly the right answer depends on the wording of the question. Thus it is unclear to me what you need clarification about. Does the question relate specifically to the video? Can you give the times in the video where the speaker says the things that confuse you?

Comment: It reduces the number of people who will try to help you with your question if you expect them to watch the entire video. Thus the specific times in the video, or paraphrasing or quoting what the speaker said would help you to get answers.

Comment: Since the event “one child is a boy” *has happened*, its probability is $1$. This is not so much a paradox per se as an illustration that *conditional* probabilites run counter to many people’s intuition.

Comment: Amd, what about this: 'one child is a boy with black hair', wich are the odds the other is also a boy? or 'one child is a boy with 1,79m height'? Why this takes the probability closer to 1/2 invariabily?

Answer (score 3):

> If he is introducing at random isnt introducing a boy the double the odds in the boy/boy subgroup? [BB; BG; GB; GG] arent the odds: [50;25;25;0]?

There's no "double the odds" happening here.   What you are measuring is the ratio of outcomes for "boy and girl" among those of the given criteria; when all outcomes have equal probability.

It comes down to the difference between "at least one" and "this particular one".

---

**I:** Bob Smith brings his two new babies to the park in a stroller on a cold day. He tells some anecdotes, and thus reveals that *at least one* of them is a boy. The probability that the other is a girl is $2/3$.

$$\require{enclose} \rm \enclose{circle}{\bbox[1ex]{BB, \underbrace{BG, GB}}}, GG$$

---

**II**: Bob Smith brings his two new babies to the park in a stroller on a cold day. He tells some anecdotes, *and points* to reveal that *a particular one* of them is a boy. The probability that the other is a girl is $1/2$.

$$\require{enclose} \rm \enclose{circle}{\bbox[1ex]{BB, \underbrace{BG}}}, GB, GG$$

---

**III**: Bob Smith brings his two new babies to the park in a stroller on a cold day. He tells some anecdotes, to reveal that *at least one* of them is a boy that was born on Tuesday.

- In this case the sample space consists of $14^2$ outcomes

$$\begin{array}{|l|c{:c}|} \hline L\backslash R & \rm B_{M} & \rm B_{Tu} & \rm B_{W} & \rm B_{Th} & \rm B_{F} & \rm B_{Sa} & \rm B_{Su} & \rm G_{M} & \rm G_{Tu} & \rm G_{W} & \rm G_{Th} & \rm G_{F} & \rm G_{Sa} & \rm G_{Su}\\ \hline 
 \rm B_{M} & \times& \circ & \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times\\ \hdashline 
 \rm B_{Tu} & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\ \hdashline
 \rm B_{W} & \times& \circ & \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times\\ \hdashline
 \rm B_{Th} & \times& \circ & \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times\\ \hdashline
 \rm B_{F} & \times& \circ & \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times\\ \hdashline
 \rm B_{Sa} & \times& \circ & \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times\\ \hdashline
 \rm B_{Su} & \times& \circ & \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times\\ \hdashline
 \rm G_{M} & \times& \bullet & \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times\\ \hdashline
 \rm G_{Tu} & \times& \bullet & \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times\\ \hdashline
 \rm G_{W} & \times& \bullet & \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times\\ \hdashline
 \rm G_{Th} & \times& \bullet & \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times\\ \hdashline
 \rm G_{F} & \times& \bullet & \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times\\ \hdashline
 \rm G_{Sa} & \times& \bullet & \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times\\ \hdashline
 \rm G_{Su}& \times& \bullet & \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times& \times \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

- $14$ of these outcomes have the left child a boy born on a Tuesday, and $14$ of these have a right child a boy born on a Tuesday, *however* there is a common outcome that has both children a boy born on a Tuesday (so don't over count this).   In total $14+14-1$ outcomes of the sample space have *at least one* child that is a boy born on a Tuesday.   Indicated above as black and white circles.
- Among these, $7$ elements consist of a boy born on Tuesday then a girl, and $7$ are a girl then a boy born on a Tuesday.   Indicated above as the black circles.
- So the (conditional)probability that the family consists of a boy and a girl when given that at least one child is a boy borne on a Tuesday is: the ratio of black circles to all circles. $$\dfrac{7+7}{14+14-1}=\dfrac{14}{27}\approx 0.51{\small 8}$$

---

Assuming that: There is a equal chance of each child being a boy or a girl, an equal chance of each child being born on any particular day, and these events are mutually independent. (IE: all outcomes in the sample space have equal probability)

Comment: What about this: they are twins, he reveals that one particular of them is a boy. Answer: 1/2. He scramble them and you cant differentiate who is who, the odds are now 1/3? Why is the information different than just saying 'at least one of them is a boy' if they are scrambled and thats all you can tell?

Comment: About case III, but the information you have is that 'at least one of them' is a boy, born on tuesday. He is not telling you that a particular child is a boy, shouldnt approximately the result be closer to 1/3 than 1/2? What we are measuring is the outcome of both boys, I still cant understand logically why it is 51,8% considering this: If he have a boy, born os wednesday, wich are the odds the other child is a boy? 51,8%, and the same for everyother day of the week. If everyday of the week have the outcome 51,8% how it can be 1/2 if you dont specify the day the boy is born?

Comment: In case III, if we remove the day the boy was born the answer is 1/3 or 1/2? The way I see it seems 1/3.

Comment: @eJunior Does the new table help?  PS: The probability that both are boys given that at least one is a boy born on Tuesday is: $$\frac{7+7-1}{14+14-1}=\frac{13}{27}\approx 0.48{\small 1}$$

Comment: PPS: Twins complicates matters since it invalidates the assumption of independence.  (Twins are much more likely to be born on the same day or adjacent days.)

Comment: When I refered to twins I wasnt refering to case 3, but case 1, sorry I wasnt specific.

Comment: About the new table, I think I understand that it deviates from 1/2 because we are considering (for right or wrong) that 'the odds for a boy being born on tuesday is the same if Bob have 1 or 2 boys'. So it falls short of 1/2. But if you remove the date, suddenly the answer turns out to 1/3. Consider this: *Bob Smith brings his two new babies to the park in a stroller on a cold day. He tells some anecdotes, to reveal that at least one of them is a boy*. The answer is 1/3, right? So why does the date makes it fall short of 1/2?

Comment: What if Bob says this: *one of them is a boy, who is born either on sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday or saturday*. Case 3 or Case 1 (as in your response) only difference is specifing the date that the boy was born.

Comment: Lets say Bob didnt told you the day his boy was born, but he will. And when he says the day the boy was born you need to say the chances that the other child is a girl. The chances before or after he says the day shouldnt be any different.

Comment: @eJunior Of course the measure of probability *may* be different under different conditions of knowledge.  That's what conditional probability is all about.

Comment: But the information you are having is not different (in the case of days of the week) nor you are being given less information (in the case of the twins). Its the same information just portraited different. The point is Bob can say any day of the week as his boys birth, and his answer doesnt matter because it wouldnt affect yours. you arte not giving different answer is he says his boy is born on monday than if he says his boy is born on friday.

Comment: I think Im understanding now. If the case was that: *His firstborn was a boy born on tuesday.* than it would be 1/2, is this correct? And if you said: *at least one child is a boy born on anyday of the week but saturday.* The answer would somehow approach 1/3 but not quite get there? So when you say the days of the week the more you specifies the closer it gets to 1/2, and the less you specify the closer it gets to 1/3, is this it? If thats the case than it makes sense to me, I think this is the trouble I was having.

Answer (score 1):

The key issue for the first example is this "If he is introducing at random..."

He isn't. You have already been told that he introduced a boy. If I came to you before any of this happened and said "Mr. Smith will introduce a random child to you. What do you think his other child will be?" Then it would be correct for you to say 50/50 boy/girl.

If he hadn't introduced a child yet, you could say that there is a 2/3 chance that the second child will be the opposite gender of the first. Once the first child is introduced, you know which 2/3-1/3 split you are looking at.

I do not understand what you are asking with the day of the week paradox.

Comment: That doesn't mean that he didn't introduce at random. This is a case of conditional probability.

Comment: I understood what you meant. Like if everything is coincidential than the answer is 1/2, if it is a controlled environment than it may be 1/3. But what about when you specify the day of the week? It is neither 1/3 nor 1/2. Supposing it is a controlled environment, where you selected only the people that have 2 children, at least one boy, born on tuersday.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of these questions ultimately traces back to Martin Gardner's May, 1959 column in Scientific American. He asked: "Mr. Smith has two children. At least one of them is a boy. What is the probability that both children are boys?" Most people only remember that he said the answer was 1/3. What they don't remember, is that he retracted that answer the next October. The answer depends on how you learned the information "at least one is a boy." If you learned it by a process that would tell you that answer for every family that included a boy, then 1/3 is indeed correct.

But if you could have learned about a girl just as easily - for example, a father telling anecdotes about his two new babies is just as likely to reveal that at least one is a girl, as to reveal that at least one is a boy - then the answer is 1/2. Note that I'm not saying that the anecdote reveals the gender of a *particular*, just that you can learn about a girl or a boy when there is one of each, and the 1/3 answer requires that you can only learn about a boy from an anecdote.

Now, suppose it was Sherlock Holmes who hears the anecdotes. He says "Interesting, Watson, from those stories I was able to deduce the day of the week that a boy from that family was born. Can you guess what day that is?" If you are Watson, you probably learned nothing that would let you favor one day over another, so they all must be the same. Since they must add up to 1, you can only think that there is a 1/7 chance for each day.

But if you look at Graham Kemp's table, there are 196 combinations. And no matter what day it is that Holmes deduced, there are 27 combinations that include a boy born on that day. So it seems the chances should be 27/196, which is a little less than 1/7. Unless we can find an error in one of these answers, this is a paradox.

It is actually a form of what is known as Bertrand's Box Paradox. Joseph Bertrand did not use the word "paradox" to refer the puzzle itself, but to how to tell which answer has the error. The chances that Holmes deduced "Tuesday" can't change from 1/7 to 27/196 just because he told you about the deduction, to the error lies in that calculation.

In fact, if the family includes a boy born on a Tuesday, and (say) a girl born on a Thursday, then there should be a 50% chance Holmes would have made a different deduction. There can only be a 100% chance if both are Tuesday Boys. Using this method, there is one combination where Holmes could only deduce "Tuesday Boy," and 26 where there was only a 50% chance. The answer to Graham Kemp question isn't (7+7)/(14+14-1)=14/27, it is (7/2+7/2)/(13/2+13/2+1)=7/14=1/2.